# History в AutoKeras

Tags: python, keras

У меня есть объект класса autokerаs, который автоматически строит нейронку  модели регрессии, обучается на подаваемом датасете и записывает историю обучения. Хотелось бы посмотерть историю обучения каждой попытки (в даном случае их три, т.к. max_trials=3). Но строчка hist = pd.DataFrame(REGG.history) сохраняет только полседнюю историю обучения. Подскажите, нет ли возможности это модифицировать, чтобы просматривать историю обучения любой попытки? Заранее спасибо за ответ.

```
import autokeras as ak
train_set = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, Y_train))
test_set = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_test, Y_test))

reg2 = ak.StructuredDataRegressor(max_trials=3,
                                  overwrite=True,
                                  project_name="AutoKeras4",
                                  loss='mean_absolute_error',
                                  metrics = 'accuracy'
                                  )
# Feed the tensorflow Dataset to the regressor.
REGG = reg2.fit(train_set, verbose=True, epochs=50)

hist = pd.DataFrame(REGG.history)
hist['epoch'] = REGG.epoch
```

Comment: Согласно документации какие-то данные по эпохам должны быть вроде в `REGG.history.history`, если я правильно прочитал описание https://autokeras.com/structured_data_regressor/ А, хотя нет, это наверное всё-равно только для самой успешной модели.

Comment: в том-то и дело, что тут для последней, а не для самой успешной

Comment: что-то толкового не нашел вообще ни в документации, не в их книге https://bookskeeper.ru/knigi/programmirovanie/206139-automated-machine-learning-in-action.html